# Why copying styles ends being so messed up in devtools?

Tags: javascript, css, svelte, devtools

Copied from Chrome Devtools

[image: Ctrl+V in VS Code]

Pasted in VS Code

[image: Ctrl+C from Chrome Devtools]

**MY GUESS:** It probably has to do with Chrome's new unit switching dropdown. So, is it really a bug. Or I'm doing something wrong.

---

I'm using svelte though. But I'm sure it doesn't have to do anything with the problem.
I tried pasting in notepad too. Same result.

Comment: Why? Just a guess but maybe because it was never intended to be copied from. If you want a definitive answer, reach out to the Chromium community. FYI, you can probably get a better source from the _Sources_ panel

Comment: Or even right-click on the classname and select _"Copy all declarations"_

Comment: Great. But it used to work. What if you want to copy a number of declaration but not all of them.  Surely gives you more flexibility.

Comment: Can confirm it used to work perfectly for the past years. I was using this same methond to copy test-code to vscode. Now it does the same error. The quick solution is to get used to right-click and copy all declarations.

Comment: Update your chrome to last version, Problem fixed in Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @HosseinBajan Indeed. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 5):

If you right click you can select "copy selector" to get

```
.event
```

and if you click "copy rule" you get

```
.event {
    position: absolute; //etc.
}
```

and if you click "copy all declarations" you get:

```
position: absolute; //etc.
```

[image]